# Set value of WinForms Chart label

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to draw a chart from SQL-Data, which currently looks like this:
[image]

This is the table `db.GetTable(cmdGraph)` returns:
[image]

How do I manage to change the labeling of the pie-parts to display the value of the field `Count` so that it looks like this?

[image]

---

This is the code that I use to draw the chart:

```
private void UpdateEvaluation(SqlCommand cmdGraph)
        {
            chPie.DataSource = db.GetTable(cmdGraph);
            chPie.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Value";
            chPie.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Count";
            chPie.DataBind();
        }
```

And this is how it gets called:

```
UpdateEvaluation(new SqlCommand("SELECT Value, Count(*) as Count " +
                        "FROM DV.dbo.tbDefender " +
                        "WHERE Class LIKE 'Operating System' " +
                        "AND Type LIKE 'Caption' " +
                        "GROUP BY Value " +
                        "ORDER BY Count DESC "));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself:

```
chPie.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

The value `IsValueShownAsLabel` has to be set. Either programatically or through the Designer (In Properties under Chart *Series* and then look for *IsValueShownAsLabel* under Label)